# Scope of window.URL.createObjectURL (html5)

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm building an html5 application and I'm struggling with the scope of the createObjectURL method.
To give you some information on my application to help you understand my issue:
- page 1: the user submits his video and I'm fetching info about his video (IMDB info mainly)
- page 2: this is the page where the video is actually played.

Now my question: when the user submits his video on page 1, can I create the blob url (createObjectURL method) and pass it to page 2 to play the video or is it out of scope?

The explanation is rather ambiguous on [this page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/): "Blob URLs are unique and last for the lifetime of your application (e.g. until the document is unloaded)": page 1 and page 2 are in the same application but the document will be unloaded between those two pages right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that indeed **blob URLs in html5 have only the page as a scope**!
The two solutions that I found to tackle the problem described above are:
1. Put everything in the same page (you can modify the page with js for example)
2. Or use an iframe to load the second page "in" the first one.

Hope that can help someone out there.